# Scala's function as parameter usage

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
class ClosureClass {
  def printResult[T](f: => T) = {
    println("choice 1")
    println(f)
  }

  def printResult[T](f: String => T) = {
    println("choice 2")
    println(f("HI THERE"))
  }
}

object demo {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val cc = new ClosureClass
    cc.printResult()   // call 1
    cc.printResult("Hi")  // call 2
  }
}
```

I play with the above code, and the result showed me. I have two questions

1) why both call 1 and call 2 go into choice 1?

2) How can I pass a parameter so that I can get into choice 2.

Thanks,

```
choice 1
()
choice 1
Hi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type `=> T` means that `f` is a call-by-name parameter.  This means that `f` is of type `T`, and the expression passed into the function will be evaluated when it is used (not when the function is called.

The type `String => T` means that `f` is a `Function[String,T]`, that is, a function from a `String` to a `T`.

When you call with `"Hi"`, a `String` as the argument, Scala sees that there are two choices for `printResult`:

1) `=> T`: In this case case `T` would bind to `String`, which is fine.

2) `String => T`: This does not work since `String` is not a function from `String` to anything... it's not a function at all.

How you fix this depends on what you are trying to do.  If you just want to fix how `printResult` is being called, then you call call it with:

```
val g: (String => String) = (s: String) => s + "***"
cc.printResult(g)
```

which prints:

```
choice 2
HI THERE***
```

since you are now are now correctly passing a *function*, `g`, from `String` to some `T`.  That `T` here is `String`, since the function is just adding `***` onto the end of whatever it is passed and returning the modified string.